# Simple AJAX request application

Tags: javascript, ajax

Today I created my first simple AJAX application. It works fine, but I am a bit unsure if I did everything correct. I'd like to use the code as template for future projects.

```
function _solve(id) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
        var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
        if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === OK) {
                obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (obj.success) {
                    if (document.getElementById('line'+obj.id).style.display != 'none') {
                        document.getElementById('line'+obj.id).style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = document.getElementById('count').innerHTML - 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('Json error: ' + obj.error);
                }
            } else {
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.status); // An error occurred during the request.
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', 'ajax_cmd.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('cmd=solve&id='+id);
}
```

Beside general improvement suggestions, I have following particular questions:

1. Do I need to somehow close the connection? It looks like `send()` automatically closes the connection because I cannot execute `send()` twice.
2. Is the error handling ok? When my internet connection was a bit unstable, I got the message "Error: 0". Zero sounds like a strange status code.

Note: For now, I'd like to stick with plain JavaScript, without jQuery or other frameworks.

Explanation/context of the code:

The HTML page has a table. Each table row  represents a dataset with an ID. The id of each row is "line" plus the dataset ID, e.g. "line1". Each table row has a link named "Solve" which calls the JavaScript function `_solve(id)`.

```
<tr id="line61087">
  <td>php/error.log</td>
  <td><a href="javascript:_solve(61087)">Solve</a></td>
  <td>1113</td>
  <td>2017-09-03&nbsp;01:18:18</td>
  <td>Xyz...</td>
</tr>
```

When the user clicks at "Solve", a PHP script (ajax_cmd.php) is called with AJAX. The PHP script deletes the dataset and confirms the deletion with the JSON object `success: true; id: (the ID)` on success or `success: false; error: (the error message)` on failure.

After the PHP script confirmed the successful deletion, the AJAX script hides the table row and decreases a row counter.

A double-click prevention (which might result in a double-decrease of the counter) is realized with a check if the row is already hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start off with your questions:

> Do I need to somehow close the connection? It looks like send() automatically closes the connection because I cannot execute send() twice.

No. The browser abstracts all connection details from you, like connection persistence, caching, protocols, etc. You just have to think that an instance of `XMLHttpRequest` represents one request-response pair.

> Is the error handling ok? When my internet connection was a bit unstable, I got the message "Error: 0". Zero sounds like a strange status code.

A zero status code is a non-HTTP status code for a generic network failure. You can get that status code from invalid certificate errors, cross-domain errors, extensions blocking the connection, etc. On JS, you often cannot get any specific information from the error, and the only thing you can do is show a generic error message on your app. However, the browser console will tell you what happened exactly.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Is so 2010. There's a simpler [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that does more with a simpler syntax. Consider using that instead. It's inspired greatly by jQuery. If you're familiar with jQuery, you pretty much know what to do.

```
    var DONE = 4; // readyState 4 means the request is done.
    var OK = 200; // status 200 is a successful return.
    if (xhr.readyState === DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === OK) {
```

Unless you're reusing `DONE` and `OK` elsewhere, it's pointless to put them in variables. If one sees xhr code done manually, it's pretty much standard to check readyState 4 and status 200 when expecting a success.

```
obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

`JSON.parse` can throw an error when the string is malformed JSON. And malformed JSON can be caused by bad server code, or a misconfigured server that returns HTML error pages on errors. Wrap this in a `try-catch`, and fail the operation if it does throw.